Simple Sprite Animation Not Playing As Intended
I have a simple animation for lava that I want to play. Ideally, it should play only when visible on the screen, BUT for now, it is set to always animate (screenshot attached).

Each Lava Pool has 1 LavaAnimation, and a number of SpriteMask LavaTiles. The LavaAnimation is scaled so that it is large enough to cover all tiles.

However, the "visible on screen" part doesn't seem to be working as intended. What did I do wrong?
For clarity, the brown circle is the player. This is when the animation DOES play (please note the center of the animation is shown on scene view, so animation is definitely "visible"):

And yet this is when animation does not play despite being fully on screen:

Per a comment left by BugFinder, here is an additional screenshot. The lava is not animating here (even though it should, see the game window where that particular pool of lava is visible on the camera). In the scene view on the left, the big square is the animation game object, and the small squares are the tiles with SpriteMasks on them.

UPDATE: here is my code spawning the pool of lava. The most relevant parts probably, is the fact that I spawn it then move it.
In this code, lavaPool is just a transform.
lavaAnim is the gameobject with the animation on it.
The CreatePool function adds in the tiles of spriteMasks. I have also attached the CreatePool function below.
            Transform lavaPool = Instantiate(poolPrefab);
        lavaPool.position = randomPos;

        TerrainObject lavaAnim = Instantiate(lavaAnimation);
        lavaAnim.transform.localScale = lavaPool.localScale.x * size * Vector3.one;
        lavaAnim.transform.parent = lavaPool;
        lavaAnim.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        CreatePool(lavamap, lavaPool);
        lavaPool.parent = chunk.transform;

The CreatePool function:
    protected void CreatePool(bool[,] lavaMap, Transform lavaPool)
    {
    Vector3 initPosition = new Vector3
    (
        -(size - 1)/2f,
        0,
        -(size - 1)/2f
    );

    for (int x = 0; x < lavaMap.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < lavaMap.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            if (lavaMap[x, y] == true)
            {
                Vector3 pos = initPosition;
                pos.x += x;
                pos.z += y;
                Transform tile = Instantiate(lavaTile);
                tile.parent = lavaPool.transform;
                tile.localScale = Vector3.one;
                tile.localPosition = pos;
            }
        }
    }
}


Its hard to answer about "visible on screen" when you havent shared the code

Visible on screen is not my code, its a setting on the Animator component itself - I assumed it meant visible to the main Camera, but it's possible I might be mistaken about which Camera/the criteria it uses

I have added an additional picture that should hopefully make it more obvious what the structure of my Game Objects are.

well as youve set culling mode to always (which is what you were referring to) this doesnt apply, so, if its not animating, its suggesting it has no idea its supposed to be.

Could you please elaborate as to what you mean? I have set culling mode to always animate, yet it only sometime animates, depending on where my player is standing, suggesting that there is still some kind of check happening that I'm unaware of

well we cant see from what you shared, if its set to always then its not the animator which is stopping it from working, you need to look elsewhere... wherever there is is your code.

I was focusing too hard on the settings, I didn't think it was my code. I have now attached the spawning code to the question. I have also tried instantiating the Animation  with the correct position, rotation and parenting (i.e. Instantiate(prefab, position, quaternion, parent), but this did not fix the issue.
